# Selenium ChromeDriver gives me SerializationException every time I try to run it

Tags: selenium, nunit

I have created NUnit suite that initialises Chrome Webdriver in Selenium. This works fine with InternetExplorer driver and Firefox driver however fails with SerializationException every time I try to run it with Chrome driver.

Anyone can point me in right direction?

```
namespace TestNamespace
{
using System;
using NUnit.Framework;
using NUnit.Core;
using SeleniumTests;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.IE;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;

  class AllInOne
  {
    public static IWebDriver WebDriver { get; private set; }

    [Suite]
    public static TestSuite Suite
    {
        get
        {
            TestSuite suite = new TestSuite("All Tests");

            SetupChrome();

            suite.Add(new FlashLoadedTest { Driver = WebDriver });

            return suite;
        }
    }


    private static void SetupChrome()
    {
        WebDriver = new ChromeDriver(@"C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application");
    }
  }
}
```

This is error I get:

```
Unhandled Exception:
System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Unable to find assembly 'WebDriver, Version=2.15.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1c2bd1631853048f'.

Server stack trace:
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryAssemblyInfo.GetAssembly()
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.GetType(BinaryAssemblyInfo assemblyInfo, String name)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectMap..ctor(String objectName, String[] memberNames, BinaryTypeEnum[] binaryTypeEnumA, Object[] typeInformationA, Int32[] memberAssemIds, ObjectReader objectReader, Int32 objectId, BinaryAssemblyInfo assemblyInfo, SizedArray assemIdToAssemblyTable)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectMap.Create(String name, String[] memberNames, BinaryTypeEnum[] binaryTypeEnumA, Object[] typeInformationA, Int32[] memberAssemIds, ObjectReader objectReader, Int32 objectId, BinaryAssemblyInfo assemblyInfo, SizedArray assemIdToAssemblyTable)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.ReadObjectWithMapTyped(BinaryObjectWithMapTyped record)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.ReadObjectWithMapTyped(BinaryHeaderEnum binaryHeaderEnum)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.Run()
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.Deserialize(HeaderHandler handler, __BinaryParser serParser, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream, HeaderHandler handler, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.CrossAppDomainSerializer.DeserializeObject(MemoryStream stm)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.CrossAppDomainSerializer.DeserializeMessageParts(MemoryStream stm)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.SmuggledMethodReturnMessage.FixupForNewAppDomain()
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.CrossAppDomainSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage reqMsg)

Exception rethrown at [0]:
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at NUnit.Core.TestRunner.Load(TestPackage package)
   at NUnit.Util.TestDomain.Load(TestPackage package)
   at NUnit.ConsoleRunner.ConsoleUi.Execute(ConsoleOptions options)
   at NUnit.ConsoleRunner.Runner.Main(String[] args)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not into NUnit, but I believe that `IWebDriver` class is for Internet Explorer **only** - but that applies to Java

Do you have class `WebDriver` also? If yes, try using it.